# apply HPA for Statefulset in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kubernetes-statefulset

I am trying to setup HPA for my statefulset(for elasticsearch) in kubernetes environment. I am planning to scale the statefulset using the cpu utilization. I have created the metric server from https://github.com/stefanprodan/k8s-prom-hpa/tree/master/metrics-server.

and my HPA yaml for statefulset is as folows:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: dz-es-cluster
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: StatefulSet
    name: dz-es-cluster
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      targetAverageUtilization: 80
```

But getting output in hpa as follows:

```
Conditions:
  Type         Status  Reason          Message
  ----         ------  ------          -------
  AbleToScale  False   FailedGetScale  the HPA controller was unable to get the target's current scale: the server could not find the requested resource
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                From                       Message
  ----     ------          ----               ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetScale  1m (x71 over 36m)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  the server could not find the requested resource
```

someone please help me..

Comment: My kubernetes version is  "v1.8.15"

Comment: Could you please share output of `kubectl top nodes`?

Comment: @PrafullLadha, these this the output.

`root@ip:~# kubectl top nodes
NAME                            CPU(cores)   CPU%      MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
ip-***-20-32-***.ec2.internal   1454m        9%        18392Mi         28%       
ip-***-20-34-***.ec2.internal   2130m        13%       31761Mi         49%`

Comment: Your metrics server is running fine. Did you specify the `resources` section in your statefulset. That is required section for HPA to work. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/

Comment: There is an entry for resources in my statefulset yaml and CPU limit is set to 1 and request to 0.25. Yes, my metrics server is running fine. I have tested its working by autoscaling one of my Deployment. Issue is only with statefulset.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The support for autoscaling the statefulsets using HPA is added in kubernetes 1.9, so your version doesn't has support for it. After kubernetes 1.9, you can autoscale your statefulsets using:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: YOUR_HPA_NAME
spec:
  maxReplicas: 3
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: StatefulSet
    name: YOUR_STATEFUL_SET_NAME
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
```

Please refer the following link for more information:

> https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44033