# How to spawn statefulsets pod when new node added to cluster( like daemonsets)? Using helm for deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Statefulsets running in K8s cluster as below:

Node 1: app-0
Node 2: app-1
Node 3: app-2

When new node added to cluster, how to ensure new pod (app-4) will be spawned in the new node ?

Deploying using helm(not using operator)

Comment: How do you make sure one sts pod run on one node ? Two sts pods can run in same node know.

Comment: If a new node is added, do you always want a new pod to be launched there (and if so, why)?  Or are you just trying to put the pods on different nodes (and if so, why)?

Comment: Please: 1- Fix your title, there is some mixing words confusing it. 2 - Are you using a public helm chart? Or are you creating a helm chart? 3-  You can read this guide [How to deploy a Statefulset where you get one pod per node (like a Daemonset) StatefulDaemonSet](https://medium.com/@johnjjung/building-a-kubernetes-daemonstatefulset-30ad0592d8cb) to get a better idea. Provide more practical info otherwise the advices will be very general.

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian Using Node Anti affinity

Comment: @david  Yes I have requirement that when sts pod should launch when new node added.

Comment: @RajenPatel Can you share the use case at high level ? And also why it is not possible to use Daemonset for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a combination of [Node Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/03/advanced-scheduling-in-kubernetes/) & [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54664782/1753098) for this use-case.